# Como poner tipografía en una firma html

Tags: html, fuentes, html-correo

Tengo una consulta con respecto a las firmas html pero en la parte de fonts o tipografía, el diseñador con el que trabajo me paso una tipografía en un archivo GillSans.otf y tengo que colocarlo en una firma pero no se como y he investigado pero solo se lo obvio que es subir a un host y llamarlo desde el css, pero ahora no tengo hosting, y el cliente me esta pidiendo esa tipografía.

En resumen como haría para colocarla?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que importar la fuente desde tu archivo CSS (suponiendo que este en el directorio fonts):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: testfont;
    src: url("fonts/test.otf") format("opentype");
}

.fonttest {
    font-family: 'testfont';
}
```

Y despues en el HTML llamarlo de esta forma:

```
<p class="fonttest">TESTtest</p>
```